# Java SAX parser & multiple ContentHandlers

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, saxparser

I've written a Java SAX parser, on Android, using `XmlReader` and `DefaultHandler`.

Its growing size has become unwieldy so what I want to do is delegate responsibility for content beneath certain elements to 'child' handlers.

Suppose I have the XML:

```
<fruit>
   <apples>
      <pips/>
   </apples>
   <oranges>
      <seeds/>
   </oranges>
</fruit>
```

I intended to have the original handler implementation handover to separate respective handlers for apples, oranges etc, and have those hand back when done.

Therefore, I do something a bit like this:

```
@Override
public void startElement( ... ) ...
{
   //...

   if ( localName.equals("oranges"))
   {
       ContentHandler orangeHandler = new OrangeHandler( xmlReader, this );
       xmlReader.setContentHandler( orangeHandler );
   }

   super.startElement( uri, localName, qName, attributes );
}
```

and then restore the main handler in a similar way.

**What I expect to see**: further calls to startElement(), characters(), endElement() etc go to the new handler.

**What I actually see**: that, but continued calls to those methods on the main handler as well.

Javadoc says:

> public void setContentHandler(ContentHandler handler)
>
> Allow an application to register a content event handler.
>
> If the application does not register a content handler, all content events reported by the SAX parser will be silently ignored.
>
> Applications may register a new or different handler in the middle of a parse, and the SAX parser must begin using the new handler
>   immediately.

I can get around the reporting behaviour by keeping my own record of whether I'm delegating or not, and ignoring those surplus calls, but it makes me wonder if I'm doing something stupid that will bite me later.

Does anyone have experience of this?

Comment: I just did just that - register a new content handler in my startElement method and all "trafic" went to the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's perhaps easier to maintain your original SAX parser that issues your callbacks, and substitute in separate handlers underneath that simply proxy the SAX callback methods with different implementations, but *don't perform the actual XML reading*, as you're currently doing.

e.g. (in pseudocode)

```
class SaxHandler {
   SaxProxy proxy = new SaxProxyImpl();
   public void startElement(e) {
      proxy.startElement(e);
   }
}
```

and swap your `proxy` to a different implementation as required. I suspect you'll need a stack of proxies, and pop your stack upon the appropriate `endElement()` callback.

Comment: The stack-based proxy idea is neater than in-object parent/child relationships, so I like that. The object hierarchy created in the parse still needs to be propagated back up from each stage though, so I need to think about how that translates.

Answer (score 0):

As a resolution, I've found this to be a bug in my own code - compared to the code in the question, the more complicated reality is that I have multiple levels of delegation, plus reprocessing of the delegation point, i.e.

```
   if ( localName.equals("oranges"))
   {
       ContentHandler orangeHandler = new OrangeHandler( xmlReader, this );
       xmlReader.setContentHandler( orangeHandler );
       orangeHandler.startElement( ..., localName, ...);
   }
```

In doing so, I had inappropriate ordering of the content handler and startElement calls, which - when delegating down for a second time - conspired to set the wrong handler.

I don't think it reduces all my complexities, but @Brian's choice of design would have simplified the delegation of parsing flow itself, so I'm accepting that as the answer.